# Type ORM best way to query a many to many relationship

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am new to TypeORM and having a bit of trouble with a query. Given the following entities, I am trying to figure out how to query a many-to-many relationship.

What I am trying to do is get all of the organizations that a user is an admin of, would someone be able to show me how it is done?

```
import { User } from 'src/auth/user.entity';
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Organization {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  organizationId: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.organizationsCreated)
  createdBy;

  @ManyToMany(() => User, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable()
  admins: User[];
}


import { Task } from '../tasks/task.entity';
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { Organization } from 'src/organization/organization.entity';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  Userid: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Organization, (organization) => organization.createdBy)
  organizationsCreated: Organization[];

  @OneToMany((_type) => Task, (task) => task.user, { eager: true })
  tasks: Task[];
}
```

The following seems to be closest I have gotten so far, however the problem seems to be that I would need to query the many to many table, as opposed to the organiation's table. I am not to sure how to go about doing that from within the Organization Repository class.

```
@EntityRepository(Organization)
export class OrganizationRepository extends Repository<Organization> {
  private logger = new Logger('OrganizationRepository', true);

  async getUsersOrganizations(user: User) {
    return await this.find({
      where: {
        admins: {
          user,
        },
      },
      relations: ['admins'],
    });
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is
column Organization.organizationOrganizationId does not exist.

The column exists on the organization_admins_user table.

Comment: Why do you need mapping configuration in client side?

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by this? I am basically just trying to send a response of all of the organizations that the logged in user is admin of.

Comment: Ok you just need put list of organisations in user list

Comment: Oh really, is it as simple as that? I was thinking about doing that, but thought it might end up getting a little messy. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Do it and let me know if you had a problem with that.

Comment: It seems to work fine, but I am a little concerned that the user entity is going to get extremely large if I use this method. Do you know if it is possible to build a query to do this from the organisation side instead?